# What do you call the people who like themselves?

Tags: vocabulary

How do you describe a person who appreciate himself ( kinda love himself) or really talk about himself in a way of selfishness ?

Comment: Question is incomplete: shows no efforts at research.

Comment: Do any of the [synonyms of selfish](http://thesaurus.com/browse/selfish?s=t) help?

Comment: I would call that individual a narcissist.

Answer (score 3):

*Narcissist*, *self-centered*, *egotistical*, *self-absorbed*.

Answer (score 2):

Egotist.

American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition: n. A conceited, boastful person. n. A selfish, self-centered person.

Wiktionary: n. A person who talks excessively about himself. n. A person who believes in his own importance or superiority.

Answer (score 2):

[Narcissist](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Narcissist?s=t) was the first thing that came to my mind

> nar·cis·sist [nahr-suh-sist]  noun
>   1.
>   a person who is overly self-involved, and often vain and selfish.
>   2.
>   Psychoanalysis . a person who suffers from narcissism, deriving erotic gratification from admiration of his or her own physical or mental attributes.